# get seconds from pandas timedelta with pyarrow dtype

Tags: pandas, pyarrow

I have a dataframe with pyarrow dtypes such as `duration[ns][pyarrow]'.

Using good old numpy dtypes, I can get the seconds using

```
foo['DURATION_NEW'].dt.total_seconds()
```

but pyarrow equivalent gives me an AttributeError:
`Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values`

Sadly, the usually helpful pandas documentation is rather short regarding pyarrow-dtype differences.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/pyarrow.html

Furthermore, I couldn't find a (official/helpful) migration guide from numpy to pyarrow backend covering this case.
I am using pandas 2.1.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error can be triggered with the example below :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"DURATION_NEW": [pd.Timedelta(minutes=60), pd.Timedelta(seconds=1000)]},
    dtype=pd.ArrowDtype(pa.duration("ns"))
)

df.dtypes
#DURATION_NEW    duration[ns][pyarrow]

df["DURATION_NEW"].dt.total_seconds()
# AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

But unfortunately, there is an open issue (*see* [apache/arrow#33962](https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/33962)) because pyarrow can't compute functions for timedeltas yet (*see* [pandas-dev/pandas#52284](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/52284)).

As a workaround, you can try using [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html)/ [`Timedelta.seconds`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.seconds.html#pandas.Timedelta.seconds) :

```
df["DURATION_NEW"].apply(lambda td: td.seconds)

# 0    3600
# 1    1000
# Name: DURATION_NEW, dtype: int64
```

Or with a listcomp :

```
[td.seconds for td in df["DURATION_NEW"]]
# [3600, 1000]
```